# Fixing the width and height of the post thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, post, thumbnails

I'm having trouble trying to set the width and height of my post thumbnail.

Here is the link for the image

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/postthumbnail_zpsbe1027f9.png

As you can see both of the post have different dimensions

I have tried a couple of times in fixing the height and width of my post in fuction.php but no luck. Basically what i want to accomplish is that if i upload an image in the featured image regardless of size it would come out with a height of 250px and a width of 250 px. But whatever i do it seems incorrect.

This is the code that i have encoded

index.php

```
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
```

functions.php

//post thumbnail support 3

```
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250 );
```

Am i missing something? I'm still trying to code in wordpress and PHP language. Basically i'm still a newbie. I really want to accomplish this without having to really on plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(215,152), array('class' => 'thumbnail')); ?>
```

array(215,152 you can change its value to your value which is height and width

or

you can use this which used for large images

```
<?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<img src="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" width="250px" height="250px" >';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: the latter work. Are you a wordpress developer? Thanks for the awesome solution. How did you manage to come up with the solution by the way? I mean did you use or learn from wordpress codex.

Comment: I see, i guess you know your way around wordpress.